# Python - removing empty rows or columns in a list of lists

Tags: python

I guess this problem has two parts:

1. Remove a list of exclusively empty elements from a list of lists
2. Remove an element at a certain index from every list in a list of lists if the element is always empty.

I'd like to avoid using pandas and I'm sure there's some solution involving list comprehension. You can assume the list of lists will be rectangular.

Example:

Given:

```
lol = [['a',None,'c'],[None,None,None],['g',None,'i'],['j',None,None]]
```

(edit - wrote 'None' instead of None)

return:

```
lol = [['a','c'],['g','i'],['j',None]]
```

Comment: [[first, third]for first, second, third in lol if first]

Comment: Shouldn't `lol[3][2]` be `None` instead of `'None'`?

Comment: @KlasŠ. I totally agree with you. In my answer I have consider this

Comment: What is your expected results?  -Please be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First delete empty rows:

```
result = [row for row in lol if not all(a is None for a in row)]
```

Swap rows and columns:

```
transpose = [list(i) for i in zip(*result)]
```

Second delete all empty columns (rows in transposed list):

```
transpose= [row for row in transpose if not all(a is None for a in row)]
```

And finally swap columns/rows back:

```
result = [list(i) for i in zip(*transpose)]
```

Comment: I meant for any Falsey values to be removed, not just None, but that can be fixed by writing "not a for a in row" instead of "a is None for a in row".Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about for a listcomp method:

```py
[x for x in [[y for y in z if y is not None] for z in lol] if len (x) > 0]
```

I don't recommend this as it's not really readable though.

If your lists don't contain any values apart from `None` which evaluate to false you could use (credit to Lucas M. Uriarte):

```py
[[y for y in z if y is not None] for z in lol if any(z) ]
```

Comment: This is not in agreement with statement 2 of the question. Second you can achieve this much easier like this: ```[[y for y in z if y is not None] for z in lol if any(z) ]```. I hope helpsit

Comment: I think it is doing what the questioner is asking - removing the sublist completely if it is empty after removing all the `None` values. I've added your method too here.

Comment: that was my first idea I though it was the answer until I saw the comments on the question and re-read the step 2 and check the expected output. Then I adapted my answer to what it is now.  Note in step 2 the questions says "Remove an element at a certain index from every list in a list of lists if the element is always empty", in the case the lol[3][2] be None instead of 'None', this method doesn't work.

Comment: In any case, this might just be what I understand of the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this simple approach:

```py
outs = []

for l in lol:
    tmp = []
    for x in l:
        if x:         # OR if x is not None:     !<--- as comment suggested.
           tmp.append(x)
    if tmp:      # skip empty list: 2nd one
       outs.append(tmp)
    
print(outs)
```

#### Output:

```
[['a', 'c'], ['g', 'i'], ['j', 'None']]
```

#### Make it to a fuction:

```py
matrix = [['a', 'b', 'c', '0'],
          ['0', 'None', 'x', 'y'],
          ['k', 'l', None, None],
          [0, '', '', 'x']]

def remove_empty(matrix):
    outs = []

    for l in matrix:
        tmp = []
    
        for x in l:
            if x:
                tmp.append(x)
        if tmp:      # skip empty list: 2nd one
           outs.append(tmp)
    
    return outs


print(remove_empty(matrix))

= Outputs:
[['a', 'b', 'c', '0'], ['0', 'None', 'x', 'y'], ['k', 'l'], ['x']]
```

Comment: This is probably the most readable for me. My favourite solution here based on that. (Though I'd use `if x is not None` rather than just `if x`).

Comment: The different *syntax* is fine - as long as it works. Maybe more about the *style*.  But I agreed with  you. ^^^

Comment: This isn’t doing what OP wants! It just removes lists that only have None in them and all None from all other lists!

Answer (score -1):

Probably not a very efficient answer but the best I could come up with since I don't think it's possible using list comprehension

```py
for item in lol:
  if list(set(item)) == [None]: lol.remove(item)
```

Comment: This is just removing None elements from all sublists and finally removing empty sublists. Not what the OP is asking for!

Comment: fixed, misread the question

Answer (score -1):

This one can clean your list no matter how nested it's

```
def clean_list(data):
    cleaned_list = []
    for obj in data:
        if type(obj) == list:
            sublist = clean_list(obj)  
            if sublist:
                cleaned_list.append(sublist)
        elif obj is not None:
            cleaned_list.append(obj)
    return cleaned_list
```

Comment: This is just removing None elements... not what OP asked for.

Answer (score -1):

This is the most efficient solution - actually doing what your want - I could come up with:

```
def removeEmpties(lol):
  colsCnt = len(lol[0])
  emptyRow = [None]*colsCnt
  # first remove all rows containing only None elements
  lol2 = list(lst for lst in lol if lst!=emptyRow)
  # second go through by column
  for col in range(colsCnt-1,-1,-1):
      # and now look at that column in every row
      for row in lol2:
          # if an element in the current row is not None in that column
          if row[col] is not None:
              # we do not need to look any further,
              # since this column has to remain
              break;
      else:
          # if we could not find any non-None element,
          # this column must be removed from all rows.
          for row in lol2:
              del row[col]
  return lol2

print(removeEmpties([['a' ,None,'c' ],
                     [None,None,None],
                     ['g' ,None,'i' ],
                     ['j' ,None,None]]))
                     
print(removeEmpties([['a' ,None,'c' ],
                     [None,None,None],
                     ['g' ,None,'i' ],
                     ['j' ,None,'None']]))
```

The output of above code is:

```
[['a', 'c'], ['g', 'i'], ['j', None]]
[['a', 'c'], ['g', 'i'], ['j', 'None']]
```

and you can see it in action at https://onlinegdb.com/g76VzPGfo